# Why do we call the $(y,z)$-plane non-leading here and the $x$-axis leading?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider an equilibrium state of a three-dimensional linear system, namely assume the case where the three eigenvalues $\lambda_i, i=1,2,3$, are real and $\lambda_3 < \lambda_2 <\lambda_1<0$. Then, the assocciated three-dimensional system may be reduced to the form
$$
\dot{x}=\lambda_1 x,~~~\dot{y}=\lambda_2 y,~~~\dot{z}=\lambda_3 z.
$$
Its general solution is given by
$$
x=e^{\lambda_1 t}x_0,~~~y=e^{\lambda_2 t}y_0,~~~z=e^{\lambda_3 t}z_0.
$$

Since all $\lambda_i$'s are negative, all trajectories tend to the origin as $t\to +\infty$. Furthermore, all trajectories outside of the non-leading plane $(y,z)$ approach the origin along the leading direction that coincides with the $x$-axis.

The following picture shows the phase portrait: The fewer the arrows the weaker is the rate of contraction. The leading subspace $E^L$ is one-dimensional, the two-dimensional subspace $E^{ss}$ is non-leading.

[image]

Could you please tell me why we call the $(y,z)$-plan non-leading and the $x$-axis leading? I cannot see it.

Comment: A little bit handwaving explanation is that generic trajectory tends to origin with the speed of $x$-coordinate. It's the slowest one (because it corresponds to the eigenvalue that is nearest to imaginary axis), and it "slows" down the trajectory rate of decay. Because of that all typical trajectories are tangent to $E^L$ at the origin.

Comment: What do you mean with "generic"?

Comment: If you start trajectory from point not lying on plane $x = 0$, then it will be tangent to $Ox$ at origin. This is what I mean by generic: $x = 0$ is an additional condition that should be imposed to "break this rule".

Comment: Its a little bit hard to understand for me. I guess you are trying to say the following: The more general case is that we tend to the origin tangently to the x-axis. A more special case (x=0) is that this does not happen. So one calls x the leading direction sind it fits to a more general situation?

Comment: In control theory we call the slowest trajectory as "dominant mode". Because all other trajectories decay faster and therefore are not interesting in the sense of the worst-case system behavior. I think it is the same reason here.